# Input List of Images into a cloud deployed API function

Tags: functions, wolfram-cloud

I'm new to `APIFunction` and `CloudDeploy`, but essentially, here's my situation:

I have a function (let's call it `TestFunc`) that is of the following form:

```
TestFunc[l_List, a_Image]:= ...
```

I created an API function using this function as follows:

```
TestF = APIFunction[{"l" -> "List", "a" -> "Image"}, TestFunc[#l, #a] &]
```

And then cloud deployed `TestF` using the following:

```
CloudDeploy[TestF, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

As expected, I get the standard Wolfram Cloud website saying that at least one parameter could not be interpreted, and the two slots underneath (one for l, one for a), where I can input the parameters, are empty.

My question is: How (using what syntax) can I input a list of images for variable `l`, such as: `{img1, img2, ...}` and input one image for variable `a` so that `a = img5` into input slots?

I've been reading the documentation for a while now, and have yet to stumble upon the answer for inputting images. My ultimate goal is for a user with the link to the cloud-deployed function to be able to input a list of images for `l` and the one image for `a`. Any help, or request for clarification/more details for this question, is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'd be curious too.

Comment: @Levi actually I did just a few days ago! I'll post it as a solution as soon as I get time.

Comment: @pMarkov, it would still be usefull to post the solution